# How to prove that the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to prove that the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}).$

This is my guess:

$x^2 + x + 1$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ iff $\xi \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$

where $\xi = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $\xi = \frac{-1 - i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ but this is not true as $\xi$ is a complex number.

Is my justification correct? if not, please correct me.

Comment: Yes. **If** it were reducible, you would likely get roots in the form of $a + b$ ${^3\sqrt{2}}$ (for which you could factor for $\mathbb{R}$), where $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$. However, your roots are complex, Im($b$)

Comment: Technically the roots are in the form of $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb Q]=3$, hence there is no intermediate extension of degree $2$, and it's sufficient to show $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Another way: the two roots of $x^2+x+1$ are all imaginary, hence neither of them is included in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: I think I am following the second approach in my answer

Comment: Absolutely. It's more convenient for this poblem, but the first approach is more useful for other problems.